# Changing geom_point colors depending on data (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to change the colors of my plotted points depending on the third column in my data. I'm new to R, but I suspect I need to loop through the data frame and create a new data frame from this?

Data file example:

```
lat,lon,env 
100,30,water
102,32,soil
```

I'd like to change the color to be something like:

```
if (env = "water") { color = "blue" }

else if (env = "soil") { color = "black" }
```

Full code:

```
library(maptools)
library(maps)
library(ggmap)

importedData <- read.csv("TestData.csv")

lat = importedData$lat
lon = importedData$lon
env = importedData$env
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(lat,lon))

#color = ?????

mp <- NULL
mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="gray50") 
mp <- ggplot() +   mapWorld

mp <- mp+ geom_point(aes(x=lon, y=lat) ,color=color, size=3) 
mp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all of your variables in one data frame. Then put the `color` inside the `aes` and define it as a column in the data frame. Without using the mapping additions you could use;

```
library(ggplot2)

lat <- data.frame(lat = 1:10)

lon <- data.frame(lon = 11:20)

env <- data.frame(env = rep(c("soil", "water"), 5),
              stringsAsFactors = F)

test_data <- cbind(lat, lon, env)                  

ggplot(data = test_data) +
  geom_point(aes(x = lat, y = lon, color = env)) + # color inside the aes
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "blue")) # set the colors here
```